# What is the period?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the period of the equation $-4\sin{(2x-\pi)}$ and why?   My text book answer is incorrect I believe but it is giving me a lot of grief incase I am wrong.

Comment: First show us what you have done so far. What answer are you getting, how are you getting it, and what answer does you book indicates?

Comment: 0<2(x-pi/2)<2pi

Comment: This is not a period. A function $f$ has period $c$ if $f(t+c)=f(t)$ for all $t$ in its domain and if $0<c'<c$ then $f(t+c')\neq f(t)$

Comment: okay so pi as a period. ? Sorry about the formatting. This is my first time here.

Comment: I understood that he meant the *function* $-4\sin (2x-\pi )$.

Comment: Don't worry with your formatting :)

Comment: My book tells me the period should be pi/3. I am led to believe the period is actually pi.

Comment: You are correct and the book is aparently wrong.

Comment: Yes 2pi is the period for sin(x)

Comment: Okay thanks Gustavo! I thought it might be but badly needed to be reassured. I will continue under this understanding for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The period of sine is $2\pi$ (meaning that $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$ for all $x$ and there is no smaller positive such number).

So, we have $\sin(2x-\pi)=\sin(2x-\pi+2\pi)=\sin(2(x+\pi)-\pi)$. So, if our **function** is named $f(x)$, then we can state $f(x+\pi)=f(x)$ (and, can a smaller number $0<k<\pi$ exist s.t. $f(x+k)=f(x)$?)
So, the period is $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of finding the period.

Period=$(2π/b)$

In $-4\sin(2x-π)$ $b=2$

So your period is $π$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=-A\sin(2x-a)$ and if $T$ be the period of $f(x),$

$f(x+T)=f(x)\implies -A\sin\{2(x+T)-a\}=-A\sin(2x-a)$

$\implies\sin(2x+2T-a)-\sin(2x-a)=0$ as $A\ne0$

Applying $\sin2C-\sin2D=2\sin(C-D)\cos(C+D),$

$2\sin T\cos(2x+T-a)=0$

As $\cos(2x+T-a)$ is dependent on $x,$ we can not have a constant value of $T,$ such that $\cos(2x+T-a)=0\iff f(x+T)=f(x)$

So, $\sin T=0\implies T=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer.

So, the [fundamental](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zcai/MA527-cai/HwCh11.pdf)/[prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function)/[primitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Values) period, being the least  positive  will be $\pi$